Can I use RPI to share my USB dongle internet to LAN port?
I recently bought an Asus RT-AX59U router which I wanted to use together with a Huawei 3372-325 4G USB Modem (dongle) to provide internet access.
The problem is that the router is not compatible with the modem.
So I was thinking to use another device (Raspberry Pi) which is compatible with the modem and can share its connection via LAN port to the router.
Is it possible? Does anyone know how to do this?

Are you going to connect the Pi to the routers WAN port?

Yes, that is right.

I would suggest you FIRST work out how to connect the dongle to a Pi and include in your question.

There are many USB protocols that most users are unaware of. To support all of them usually requires a computer. Most embedded devices like modems and printers only support specific USB protocols. This router appears to support a USB modem or Phone for internet access. Since many people read these answers, it should be pointed out that many routers only support USB/MSC (a USB Drive). Most likely the modem is a USB/CDC or Communications Class Device.
If a router only supports USB/MSC devices, it is unlikely you can use the router's USB port to access the internet. Instead, consider using the Raspbery Pi in Bridge Mode.
In this Raspberry Pi Stackexchange question / answer the subject is about connecting a phone's network USB port to a Raspberry Pi and passing the internet data out the Raspberry Pi's Ethernet port to a switch. It is likely the USB modem can be substituted for the phone and the same Raspberry Pi Bridge configuration may be used.

"Likely the only USB protocol the router can support" -> No, it explicitly supports USB modems: https://www.asus.com/networking-iot-servers/wifi-routers/asus-wifi-routers/rt-ax59u/ I would guess the problem is actually the modem, which predates routers with this kind of feature (see my answer).

That's interesting. I didn't know the current crop of routers could do that! Good knowledge to know.


which is compatible with the modem

I'm presuming you don't actually have the Pi yet and this is an assumption.
However, looking around online that modem may be a bit sketchy to get to work under linux -- which is probably why the router doesn't like it, because most of them are linux based1 (a bit surprising, but then Huawei  likely aren't concerned about that use case; that model is I think older than when routers started appearing with this capability).
It may still be possible with the Pi since you have much more access to the OS, but that does not necessarily mean it will be easy, eg.:
https://blog.tanatos.org/posts/huawei_e3372h-325_brovi_with_linux/
If you aren't up for that, you might as well just research a modem which is compatible with the router and spend your money on that instead of a Pi (in fact, since another modem will still probably be cheaper than a Pi, you might as well do that regardless).


That router runs AsusWRT, which is linux derived.


Thanks for the answer. I searched what modems are compatible with the router here: https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1047044/. The problem is that this page does not mention subversions (as you can see E3372 is compatible). Do you know of a modem that works with the router?

Hmmm -- looks like you are not the only one to run into this: https://www.snbforums.com/threads/asus-rt-ax53u-huawei-4g-stick-issue.85748/  ...even worse:  https://www.snbforums.com/threads/asus-rt-ax53u-not-works-3g-4g-dongle.80482/ You could search with the router and modem model; of course people rarely post stuff online because something works, but you can at least catch reports that say they don't.  Find somewhere you can buy it which will take it back no questions asked within 7 days or something (amazon is very good for that).

...You should also try updating the router firmware if you haven't.

You could still gamble on getting a Pi and trying it; if it doesn't work (I'm not saying it for certain will not), getting a modem to known to work with that will be much easier.  And if you end up not using it there they are a little bit fun for all kinds of things ;)

I am aware this will be trial and error until I find a match. My best chance is to return both items and buy a 4G router.
